# Retries from Stripe to my webhook in test mode with Stripe Checkout

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout

I use **Stripe Checkout** then, in **"test" mode**, I intentionally returned **400 http response** or timed out to response **200 http response** to **Stripe** in **"test" mode** and I waited for retries from **Stripe** for **9 hours** but **Stripe** didn't send retries to my webhook. So, I opened **[query for missed events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list) page** then **Stripe** immediately sent the retry with **the event type "setup_intent.created"** to my webhook.

[**Retry logic**](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic) says:

> In test mode, Stripe retries three times over a few hours. Webhooks can be manually retried after this time in the Dashboard, and you can also [**query for missed events**](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list) to reconcile the data over any time period.

[**Built-in retries**](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#built-in-retries) says:

> Stripe webhooks have built-in retry methods for 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx response status codes. If Stripe doesn’t quickly receive a 2xx response status code for an event, we mark the event as failed and stop trying to send it to your endpoint. After multiple days, we email you about the misconfigured endpoint, and automatically disable it soon after if you haven’t addressed it.

My questions in **"test" mode** with **Stripe Checkout**:

1. Normally to get a retry three times from **Stripe**, do I need to wait for **more than 9 hours**?
2. Immediately to get retries from **Stripe**, do I need to open **[query for missed events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list) page**?
3. Is the event type of retries from **Stripe** always **"setup_intent.created"**?
4. Does **Stripe** send a retry **three times** if **Stripe** doesn’t receive **200 http response** or doesn't quickly receive **200 http response**?
5. Does opening **[query for missed events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list) page** send a retry whether or not **Stripe** doesn't quickly receive **200 http response**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. Normally to get a retry three times from **Stripe**, do I need to wait for **more than 9 hours**?

No. From my one week experiments, at least with **Stripe Checkout**, in **"test" mode**, I found that **Stripe** doesn't send any retries to my webhook **most of the time** even if I intentionally return **400 http response** or timed out to response **200 http response** to **Stripe**.

> 3. Is the event type of retries from **Stripe** always **"setup_intent.created"**?

According to my one week experiments, at least with **Stripe Checkout**, in **"test" mode**, it is **Yes**. One by one, I returned **400 http response** for **4 event types "payment_intent.created", "payment_intent.succeeded", "charge.succeeded" and "checkout.session.completed"**, then waited for the retry from **Stripe**. Finally, **Stripe** sent **"setup_intent.created"** for **all 4 event types**.

Actually, I asked **Stripe support** about **"1" and "3" questions** **spending more than 3 or 4 hours** but they don't even know much about **Stripe** which means **horrible support eating time**. So, you better solve any problems about **Stripe** yourself because you know **Stripe** super much more than them. Or just use other payment services.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the event retries where the `type` was different from the value on the original Event object. Are you sure the ID (`evt_xxx`) of the event retries matched the original attempt?

Comment: Retries don't occur in test mode: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices

Comment: Based on: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic 
"In test mode, Stripe retries three times over a few hours. Webhooks can be manually retried after this time in the Dashboard, and you can also query for missed events to reconcile the data over any time period."

Answer (score 2):

> Normally to get a retry three times from Stripe, do I need to wait for over a few hours which is 2, 3 hours or more?

Yes, in test mode retries are automated over a short period following an initial event delivery failure. Stripe will re-attempt to deliver a test mode event up to 3 times.

> Immediately to get retries from Stripe, do I need to open query for missed events page?

You can't manually trigger an event retry via the API, this can only be done via the Dashboard.

> Is the event type of retries from Stripe always "setup_intent.created"?

The event `type` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-type) on a retry will always be the same as the original event delivery attempt. If it was a `setup_intent.created` event then the `type` field will reflect that.

> Does Stripe send a retry three times if Stripe doesn’t receive a 2xx response status code or doesn't quickly receive a 2xx response status code?

We expect to receive a `200` response ~immediately. It is recommended you return a `200` response *before* running any custom logic your webhook may need to handle, otherwise you risk the event being undelivered (even though it was processed).

> Does opening query for missed events page send a retry whether or not Stripe doesn't quickly receive a 2xx response status code?

Querying for event via the API does **not** re-attempt event delivery. The idea is that following event delivery failures, you can reconcile any missed events by querying for those objects from the API.